# XML does not transform with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to get the `ageCode` attribute from the xml below and with an xslt, put `<Adults>3</Adults>` if the `ageCode` = 10 or `<Children>0</Children>` if the `ageCode = 8.  Here is my sample xml:

```
<Root>
    <Reservations>
        <Reservation>
            <Rooms>
                <Room>
                    <Guests>
                        <Guest ageCode="10" count="3" />
                        <Guest ageCode="8" count="0" />
                    </Guests>
                </Room>
            </Rooms>
        </Reservation>
    </Reservations>
</Root>
```

I am trying to tranform it into:

```
<Reservation>
    <Rooms>
        <Room>
            <Adults>3</Adults>
            <Children>0</Children>
        </Room>
    </Rooms>
</Reservation>
```

with the follwing XSLT, but I can't get it to work (I am completely new to XSLT):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:element name="Reservation">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Root/Reservations/Reservation/Rooms/Room/Guests">
 <xsl:for-each select="Guest">
  <xsl:if test="@ageCode = '10'">
    <xsl:element name="Adults">
      <xsl:value-of select="@count"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="@ageCode = '8'">
    <xsl:element name="Children">
      <xsl:value-of select="@count"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

How does XSLT work?  By this I mean does it go from top to bottom applying templates?  I ask because you said I needed 3 templates and with each one applied, a new transformation was made.

What does the first and second template actually do?  Is there a way you could show the XML after the first is applied, then the second?  Am I understanding XSLT correctly here?

What do you mean by applies deeper templates?

Would a tool like MapForce be useful if I  have to create many XSLT's?

Comment: Whoever downvoted, care to explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 3 templates: one to discard the top 2 elements, one to match everything and just output itself and recurse, and one to do your guests -> adults transformation.

The first one is

```
<xsl:template match="Root|Reservations">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

It outputs nothing and applies deeper templates.

The second is

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

It outputs itself (that is, an element with the current name) and applies deeper templates.

The third is what you have, but just match "Guests" instead of the full path:

```
<xsl:template match="Guests">
 <xsl:for-each select="Guest">
  <xsl:if test="@ageCode = '10'">
    <Adults>
      <xsl:value-of select="@count"/>
    </Adults>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="@ageCode = '8'">
    <Children>
      <xsl:value-of select="@count"/>
    </Children>
  </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

BTW, you don't need to use `xsl:element` with a constant name, just use a literal.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Since I am new to this, I have some questions.  I will update my post.

Comment: Worked great.  Now I just have to figure out how to it when the output is really different from the input.  Here the node names where the same.